# Paragraph random UPPERCASE words after mouseenter <p>

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, uppercase, mouseenter

I have 3 Paragraphs. I need JS code to make random words in this dummy text to go uppercase after I use mouse hover event on  `P` tag. It will change randomly every 3 seconds on every paragraph that I hover.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <style>
     p {
         margin-top: 50px;
         font-size: 24px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old</p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: We're not here to do your (home-)work. Please add the relevant infos you've found during your research, what you've tried so far and what problems you have with your attempt(s) (preferable as a [mcve]).

Comment: problem is that i had this on exam. i Tried to to make something but i dont know were to start.

Comment: Honestly i dont have any clue how to do it

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('p')].forEach(elem => {
  let oldText = elem.innerHTML;
  elem.onmouseenter = () => {
    elem.onmouseenter = '';
    setInterval(() => elem.innerHTML = oldText.split('').map(word => Math.random() > 0.15 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase()).join(''), 3000);
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    p {
      margin-top: 50px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old</p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for insult and answer